# search.h c header code generating warnings. How to solve it?

Tags: c, compiler-warnings

TAKEN FROM: https://linux.die.net/man/3/hsearch_r
Using these files you can reproduce the warnings.
This is the header file that was missing. It has been added.

morse_code.h

```
#ifndef MORSE_CODE_H
#define MORSE_CODE_H
/* HASH TABLE HEADER  */ 
#include <search.h>
/* Define system variables for hash table. */
ENTRY e;
ENTRY *ep;

/* Define Morse symbols string array */
static char * morse_symbol_str[] = {
    ".-",    "-...",    "-.-.",    "-.."    
};

/* Define Corresponding characters */
static char morse_char_arr[] = {
    'A','B','C','D'
};

static void load_morse_code_into_hashtable(void) {
    const size_t capacity = sizeof(morse_symbol_str) / sizeof(morse_symbol_str[0]);
    hcreate(capacity);
    /* Assign Values to the hash table */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
        e.key = morse_symbol_str[i];
        e.data = (void*) morse_char_arr[i];
        ep = hsearch(e, ENTER);
        /* Ensure that there is no failure */
        assert(ep != NULL && "LOADING MORSE CODE HASH TABLE FAILED!!!");
    }
}

#endif
```

This is the main.c file that gets compiled.
main.c

```
/* Include required standard library headers. */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "morse_code.h"

int main(void) {
    load_morse_code_into_hashtable();
    e.key = ".-";
    ep = hsearch(e, FIND);
    printf("%s = %c\n", e.key, (char)ep->data);
    hdestroy();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

according to search.h manual in Linux this is good code. but I get warnings. How can I change the code so that it would not generate these warnings.

```
Compiling and linking files...
src/headers/morse_code.h: In function 'load_morse_code_into_hashtable':
src/headers/morse_code.h:25:12: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   25 |   e.data = (void*) morse_char_arr[i];
      |            ^
src/main.c: In function 'main':
src/main.c:7:29: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
    7 |  printf("%s = %c\n", e.key, (char)ep->data);
      |                             ^
An executable MorseCodeDecoder has been created
```

Comment: `morse_char_arr` is an array of characters, so `morse_char_arr[i]` is just a single character. It makes no sense to convert a character to a pointer.

Comment: What is `ENTRY`? [Edit] and show a [mcve]

Comment: What is `morse_symbol_str` and `morse_char_arr`? [Edit] your question.

Comment: My bad I have added the headers. ENTRY is from <search.h>

Comment: I think it should work for you now but again your compiler must have warnings on to show the warnings. If you compile with warning off it wont show for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

item.data is a void pointer.
Therefore, one has to pass a pointer.
In my case I should pass the pointer pointing to the
address of the char in memory.

which is done by the line `item.data = (void*) &morse_char_arr[i];`
Then to access the char one can use `printf("%s = %c\n", item.key, *(char*)item_ptr->data);`

```
/* Include required standard library headers. */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

/* HASH TABLE HEADER  */ 
#include <search.h>

/* GLOBAL VARIABLES */
ENTRY item;
ENTRY* item_ptr;

/* Define Morse symbols string array */
static char * morse_symbol_str[] = {
    ".-",    "-...",    "-.-.",    "-.."    
};

/* Define Corresponding characters */
static char morse_char_arr[] = {
    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M',
    'N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
    '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','&','(',')',
    '+','=','!','?','-',39,'"','/',',','@',':','.'
};

static struct hsearch_data *load_morse_code_into_hashtable(void) {
    const size_t capacity = sizeof(morse_symbol_str) / sizeof(morse_symbol_str[0]);
    /* Allocate memory for the hash table pointer */
    struct hsearch_data* hashtable = malloc(sizeof(struct hsearch_data*)); 
    /* Create the hash table */
    hcreate_r(capacity, hashtable);
    /* Create hast table item and item pointer */
    /* Assign Values to the hash table */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
        /* Load key and data into an hash-table item */
        item.key = morse_symbol_str[i];
        /* item.data is a void pointer 
         * Therefore, one has to pass a pointer
         * In my case I should pass the pointer pointing to the 
         * address of the char
         */ 
        item.data = (void*) &morse_char_arr[i];
        /* Ensure that there is no failure and load item into the table */
        assert("FAILED TO LOAD ITEM INTO HASHTABLE" &&  \
                hsearch_r(item, ENTER, &item_ptr, hashtable)
        );
    }
    /* Return the hash table */
    return hashtable;
}

static void clear_hashtable(struct hsearch_data *hashtable) {
    hdestroy_r(hashtable);
    free(hashtable);
}

int main(void) {
    struct hsearch_data* hashtable = load_morse_code_into_hashtable();
    item.key = ".-";
    hsearch_r(item, FIND,&item_ptr,hashtable);
    printf("%s = %c\n", item.key, *(char*)item_ptr->data);
    clear_hashtable(hashtable);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Code without any explanation (not even as comments) is not a good answer.

Comment: I haven't seen your edit and I'm currently not able to undo the downvote, SO tells me _"You last voted on this answer 16 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."_. But as soon as you add some explanations, I'll retract the downvote, and if your edits are actually good, I'll even might upvote it. That's the way SO works. Some of my own questions and answers have been downvoted as well. Remember, getting downvoted is not a punishment.

Comment: I added what I understood as explanation. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong or edit it thanks.